# GoogleAppsScript - unable to get events from Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Following code is suppose to get the events for July month from Google calendar

```
// The code below will retrieve all the events for the user's default calendar and
// display the description of the first event
var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
Logger.log(cal.getName());
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("July 01, 2012 EST"), new Date("July 30, 2012 EST"));
if (events[0]) {
  Logger.log(events[0].getDescription());
}
else
{
    Logger.log("No events found");
}
```

but its only printing "No events found",

I verified the calendar name its getting the correct calendar, though not getting the events

Is there anything else to verify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code for some reason is failling on my Chrome browser (versio:20.0.1132.57) , I tried with Safari and it worked this time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked as written.

Are you running this in a place where the user is not defined and the getDefaultCalendar() cannot determine the default calendar?

Comment: "Logger.log(cal.getName())" in above code, is giving correct username

Comment: Maybe check to see the events that you see are actually in the user's calendar and not in another calendar they have created. The only way I can duplicate 'No events found' is when there are no events in the default calendar. Your code looks good.

Comment: I verified the event to be present in appropriate calendar though no luck, Is there something else am missing. Am executing the script from a container at https://script.google.com on a chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

The method getDescription() will only get the **description** of the event. So if there is no description in the created event, the logger will be empty.

Try this for example:

```
function myCalender(){

var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
Logger.log(cal.getName());
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("July 01, 2012 EST"), new Date("August 10, 2012    EST"));

var eventsCount = events.length;  
for (var i = 0; i <= eventsCount -1; i++) {

var myEvent =events[i];

var myDescription = myEvent.getDescription();
var myStartTime = myEvent.getDateCreated();
var myEndTime = myEvent.getEndTime();

Logger.log(myEvent.getDescription(), myEvent.getEndTime());

}   

}
```